# Android app works while used as debugging,but crashes if testing version "app-debug" is installed

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-play-services

Please comment why it was downvoted and what should i add more
Here is logcat output

```
06-02 15:21:04.520 7986-7986/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.mayurn.engineeringhelper, PID: 7986
                                             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzcx(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbth; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbth; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbth' appears in /data/app/com.example.mayurn.engineeringhelper-2/base.apk:classes12.dex)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5187)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4782)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4722)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

In my Build.gradle (Module:app) I have

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And in build.gradle(Project) I have this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have seen these answers

1. [Firebase database dependency crashes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732364/firebase-database-dependency-crashes-app)
2. [After upgrading to google play services 8.4.0 my app crashes on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478757/after-upgrading-to-google-play-services-8-4-0-my-app-crashes-on-startup)
3. [No static method zzUr() in Firebase when I try to use Analytics with Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202644/no-static-method-zzur-in-firebase-when-i-try-to-use-analytics-with-notificatio)

All they suggest to use the same version of firebase services.
You can see that I have already done that, the only version of `ui-database` and `ui-storage` are different.

Also short note:-MultiDex is enabled and minify is disabled.

Comment: Libraries ui-xxx are from "com.firebaseui" group so their version can be different to those coming from "com.google.firebase".

Comment: So what should i do

Comment: Do try with latest version of firebase 10.2.6.

Comment: For storage , auth, database only or for all including ui libraries?

Comment: Those with group "com.google.firebase" use 10.2.6, those with group "com.firebaseui" use 1.2.0. group is the url that comes before colon (:) in a dependency.

Comment: OMG thank you very much sir.Finally its working

Comment: But i still wonder why it was downvoted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your dependencies is that your *firebaseui* library is not compatible with **firebase** library.

Check [Compatibility with Firebase / Google Play Services Libraries](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation).

You want *1.2.0* version of *firebaseui* and therefore you must update **firebase** library to **10.2.0+**.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle you need to add all the dependencies -

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Database only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI Auth onl
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'

    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
 }
```

If this doesn't fix your error then you might want to add these files as well

```
  compile "com.android.support:design:23.2.1"
  compile "com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.1"
  compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1"
```

I hope after doing all this, your issue should be long gone.
Btw for more information on this, you can check out the Git repo of Firebase - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation actually this has all the details.